# remove junk content added on paste(tinymce 3+)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried copying from a page and then paste into tinymce. Along with the source code it inserts some extra junk code as below:

```
<div class="mcePaste" id="_mcePaste" 
style="position: absolute; 
       left: -40px; 
       top: -25px; 
       width: 1px; 
       height: 1px; 
       overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

how do I get rid of the junk code. please help me solving this.

*tinymce version* 3.0

[image]

Comment: the tinymce div i feel it as junk.

Comment: post a screenshot with what junk you see

Comment: this is not junk its the id of it

Comment: whats the use of it. I dont need that extra content to show up in website.

Comment: In newer versions this extra div is not added. But need a work around for older version as i can't change the version